# How to align images for yahoo mail

Tags: html, css, email, yahoo-mail

Hello every one I want to align my social icon images for yahoo mail I try many thing but result is same I also try table-layout:fixed; style but my images still showing on left align any one help me out from this problem my code snippet is below

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <title>My Promo | Email</title>
      
      <style type="text/css">
  body {background-color:#fcfcfc;}
         /* Client-specific Styles */
         div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
         #outlook a {padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
         html{width: 100%; }
         body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
         /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
         .ExternalClass {width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
         .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing. */
         #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
         img {outline:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
         a img {border:none;}
         .image_fix {display:block;}
         p {margin: 0px 0px !important;}
         table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
         table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
         a {color: #33b9ff;text-decoration: none;text-decoration:none!important;}
   .punch{font-size:22px;color:#32fac9;line-height: 1;}
         /*STYLES*/
         table[class=full] { width: 100%; clear: both; }
         /*IPAD STYLES*/
         @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
         a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #33b9ff; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }
         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #33b9ff !important;
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 440px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 420px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 440px!important;height:220px!important;}
         img[class=col2img] {width: 440px!important;height:220px!important;}
   .punch{font-size:22px;color:#32fac9;line-height: 1;}
         
         
         }
         /*IPHONE STYLES*/
         @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
         a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #33b9ff; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }
         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #33b9ff !important; 
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 100%!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 100%!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 280px!important;height:94px!important;}
         img[class=col2img] {width: 280px!important;height:100px!important;margin-left:0px!important;margin-right:0px!important;}
         .punch{font-size:19px;color:#32fac9;line-height: 1;}
        
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
<!-- Start of preheader -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="preheader" >
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table width="600" bgcolor="#eeeeee" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;color: #000" st-content="preheader">
                                    Can't see this Email? View it in your <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #d73914">Browser </a> 
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of preheader -->       
<!-- Start of header -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="postfooter" >
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" bgcolor="#242740" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                 
                  <tr>
                    <td  width="500" height="50" align="center" style="font-size:19px;color:#32fac9;line-height: 1;">
                                                My Punch Line
                  </tr>
                  
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<!-- End of Header -->
<!-- Start of seperator -->

<!-- End of seperator --> 
<!-- Start of main-banner -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="banner">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table width="600" bgcolor="242740" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <!-- start of image -->
                                 <td align="center" st-image="banner-image">
                                    <div class="imgpop">
                                       <a target="_blank" href="#"><img width="517" border="0" height="159" alt="" border="0" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;" src="img/banner.png" class="banner"></a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- end of image -->
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of main-banner -->  
<!-- Start of seperator -->

<!-- End of seperator -->   
<!-- Start of Left Image -->      

<!-- End of Left Image -->      
<!-- Start of seperator -->

<!-- End of seperator -->   
<!-- start of Full text -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="full-text">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table bgcolor="#fff" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <!-- Title -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #282828; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;">
                                                Hello (Mr Name)
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- End of Title -->
                                          <!-- spacing -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- End of spacing -->
                                          <!-- content -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #636363; line-height: 24px; text-align: left;padding:0 10px;">
                                              Email Body

                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- End of content -->
                                          
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of Full Text -->


<!-- Start of seperator -->

<!-- End of seperator -->
<!-- Start of footer -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="footer">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" bgcolor="#eacb3c" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table bgcolor="#eee" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <!-- Social icons -->
                                    <table  width="150" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="43" height="43" align="center">
                                                <div class="imgpop">
                                                   <a target="_blank" href="#">
                                                   <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" border="0" width="43" height="43" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;">
                                                   </a>
                                                </div>
                                             </td>
                                             <td align="left" width="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                             <td width="43" height="43" align="center">
                                                <div class="imgpop">
                                                   <a target="_blank" href="#">
                                                   <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" border="0" width="43" height="43" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;">
                                                   </a>
                                                </div>
                                             </td>
                                             
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of Social icons -->
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of footer -->
<!-- Start of Postfooter -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="postfooter" >
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
   
   
   
   
   
   
            <table width="600" bgcolor="#242740" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <!-- Spacing -->
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Spacing -->
                 <tr>
                     <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;color: #282828" st-content="preheader">
                        <span style="font-size:17px;color:#fff;display:inline-block">
             Read about our
            <a target="_blank" style="color:#d73914;text-decoration:none" href="http://some.com/my-terms.html">policy.</a>
      </span> 
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                     <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;color: #282828" st-content="preheader">
                        <span style="font-size:12px;color:#fff;display:inline-block"> © 2015 all rights reserved.
      <br>
       <a href="http://www.some.com" style="color:#52b4ed">www.some.com</a>
      </span> 
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Spacing -->
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Spacing -->
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of postfooter -->      
   </body>
   </html>
```

Social icons looks great in normal html, gmail, outlook but not in yahoo my required email is yahoo in yahoo social icons view at left align not in current align i.e centere.

thanks in advance

Comment: Avoid div's in the td

Comment: I delete div's but problem is still on yahoo mail

Comment: then try to give left and right padding for td

Comment: yes u r right I handle this through padding but problem is this images ok in all email platform means center align  except not only in yahoo mail if I use padding then image align disturb on other email platforms so that's why I not use padding